# JavaScript onclick requiring two clicks to open new tab

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I have a piece of JavaScript that is suppose to open a new tab or show a popup overlay on the current page depending on certain conditions.

In order to determine which action to do, I need to append two scripts to the DOM during the `onclick` event.

The reason the scripts are appended during the `onclick` is due to the low click rate on the element.

Right now, the overlay behavior works as expected but when a new tab needs to be opened, it requires two clicks instead of one.

Below is the snippet of code for the `onclick` event:

```
button_link.onclick = function () {
  var _this = this;
  appendScript('http://example.com/script1.js', function () {
    appendScript('http://example.com/script2.js', function () {

      if (isNewWindow() || fitsDimensions(button_link.offsetHeight) || (script1Val && !script2Val)) {
        // Open a new tab
        button_link.href = button_link.href.replace('false', 'true'); // make sure param is true
        _this.onclick = 'return '+true;
        return true;
      }

      _this.onclick = 'return '+false;

      appendScript(URL_SCHEME+'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', function () {
        appendScript('http://example.com/script3.js', function () {
          // Call function from script3.js to create popup overlay
        });
      });

      return false;

    });
  });

  return false;
};
```

Comment: is it a button or an anchor? you change it's href attribute so I'm guessing it's an anchor. This `_this.onclick = 'return '+true;`is definitely wrong ... use event listeners or at least `.onclick = function` ... the reason you need two clicks is probably because you scripts are still loading.

Comment: You're correct, it is an anchor.

Comment: you could append the scripts on hover ... that would load the script before the click event and still respect the low rate thing

Comment: Thanks for your help. As it turns out, I have not been able to get it to work the way I want and I suspect it is not even possible. I did change the JavaScript to append the scripts onhover.